# Java Using Httpurlconnection for Single Sign On

Tags: java, single-sign-on, httpurlconnection

I'm building an application designed to handle single sign on to remote applications. Unfortunately the other systems are unable to work with any SSO libraries, so I will need to do a post login. I'm wondering if I could use something like Httpurlconnection to handle this task for me? I'm under the impression this will log the server into the remote application, but will not log the client user into the system. Does anybody have anymore insight on this?

Currently I'm doing something like this, but it's a security risk exposing the passwords in the html.

```
<form name="LoginForm" action="http://support.mydomainname.co/index.php?/Base/User/Login" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="scemail" value="${programCompany.username}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="scpassword" value="${programCompany.password}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Launch" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

If my thoughts are correct, we the server is getting the login session and not the browser? If this is true, is there a way to pass the session on to the browser?